# size of packet icmp with netstat TX

Tags: netstat, icmp, packet

I am confused with the size of packet icmp. I just did a simple initial netstat, where
for eth0 : TX-OK = 485

after 1 ping message is send, again I see in netstat TX-OK = 488

So, I just want to know how does the TX actually intepret the icmp packet is counted?
I thought with 1 ping , then the TX-OK will be 486? 
*edit : 1 PING is 64 bytes. so howcome number of pacet in TX differs only 3 ? (so 1 packet is counted as 21,3 bytes ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to repeat:

[image]

I recommend drop no ICMP traffic before testing.